# Can I make an object reference be named after a string in Java?

Tags: java, object

I'm trying to make an object of a class named as a variable name, like this:

```
String myString = "StringData";
StringData myObject = new StringData();
```

But for variable strings:

```
String myString = "Class1";
Class1 object1 = new Class1();
myString = "Class2";
Class2 object1 = new Class2;
```

And also, that could be run from a for loop:

```
String myString = "AddBits";
for (int i = 0, i < 4, i++) {
  myString = myString + Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
  /*What I want to figure out, because this does not work.*/myString /*Also want to be able to assign a variable's name to the name of the reference variable*/ myString = new myString();
```

Does anyone know how I would go about this?

I haven't actually tried anything, because I have no idea what could work, and I don't have any idea where even to start.

Comment: You need to read about the `Map` class.

Comment: This sounds like you want a symbolic reference to a class or variable  This is not possible as a construct in Java, nor is it, imo, a common requirement.  What is your use case for this?  There may be an alternative that you haven't considered.

Comment: Java "variable names" are a construct appearing in source code.  But generally speaking, if you're thinking "I need a variable whose name 
I will not know until run time", you're thinking about it incorrectly, The concept you are missing is the ability to look up a value by a string (or any other type) -- generally known as 'dictionary' or 'map'.